# Trying to boot from live usb stick but during startup but it says it cannot find the appropriate drivers

Tags: boot, usb, partitioning, ntfs

Former title Trying to boot from live usb stick but during startup but it says it cannot find E:/source/install.wim (error code 0x8007000B)

Recently I've been trying to make a bootable live win 10 usb.I partitioned the disk into 2 segments, a 1.1 GB FAT32 and a 50~ GB NTFS segment, because the install file is more than the 4 GB FAT32 can handle. I did so according to the instructions here https://win10.guru/usb-install-media-with-larger-than-4gb-wim-file/

> When I ask my computer to boot from USB all seems well with my computer going through the startup phases, but then when I click on install now the computer gives an error code of 0x8007000B and says it cannot find the install.wim file. The install.wim file in the ntfs partition is 4,293,193 KB, same as the one in the iso I copied it from. The error appears to mean issue or corrupt entry in the transaction log for the file system within Windows from what I've seen but I don't quite understand what that means.

The error is now that the device cannot find the drivers for installing windows.

Is there a fix for this? I'd be happy to provide any more information  I may have missed

Comment: You are making your life really hard. Look into Windows 10 To Go, it will allow you to create a Windows-To Go stick that basically does what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I cant install anything because I don't have admin rights. I forgot the password to the admin account and im using guest

Comment: searching for windows to go just brings me to optionson if I want to boot up from wintogo disks immediately, which needs admin rights to change

Comment: I see.. If you forgot the password of the admin account, the easiest option is to download the Media Creation Tool to create a Windows Install USB stick, then backup all your data, and use the stick to create a new windows install on your harddisk.

Comment: Also, once you create the usb stick (this can be done from another computer running windows), if you boot using the stick, you can press SHIFT-F10 to open a command prompt at the first screen in the setup. This can be used to backup files.

Comment: I cant download the Media Creation Tool to create a Windows Install USB stick because i don't have admin rights. I cant access other computers

Comment: You need another computer to do it as commented.

Comment: If you can't even access another computer, then you are basically screwed.

Comment: is there really no method to do this without another computer? I can install apps from the Microsoft store; Is there an app there I can use that I haven't found yet?